# Can i restore mysql database to point of time when it was just installed/factory default?

Tags: mysql

I have an application on Centos VM that uses MySQL DB.I took a MySQL backup from another such application installed on another VM and loaded the backup on my current VM. I did not take a backup before doing the restore. Is there any way for me to go back to the factory default DB like when i first installed it? Does `DROP TABLE` actually delete tables or drop data from the table?

Comment: Consider this: "mysql --initialize" as mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911115/how-to-recover-recreate-mysqls-default-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

For PIT recovery, see if `log_bin` was turned on.

`DROP` table/database/etc promptly and irrevocably removes the data and schema.  `DROP` cannot be in a transaction (until Version 8.0).

If you are hoping for a "recycle bin", be aware that `COMMITting` a transaction effectively flushes what you might think of as a recycle bin.